# GCM in android what else

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to implement google cloud messaging in my app. I have a class GCMIntentService, I add permissions to manifest and add this code to Main activity:

```
checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (savedInstanceState == null) {

    if (extras == null) {

        GlobalConfig.setAPPLICATION_ID(APP_ID);

    } else {

        GlobalConfig.setAPPLICATION_ID(extras.getInt("application_id", 0));
    }

} else {

    MY_DEBUG.print("SavedInstanceState is not null");

}

GlobalConfig.setBookmark(0);

//notifications
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
Log.i(TAG, "registration id  " + regId);

if (regId.equals("")) {


    GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);

} else {

    Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");

}
```

I get RegId, but what I need else to get messages from google? I connect with webservice. I need to send this regId to service? What should be my next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a blog post that describes how GCM works and the role of your server in the process: http://blog.andromo.com/2012/how-does-airbop-push-messaging-work/ In the article you can simply substitute your servers for the AirBop servers.

Your next step is to send the registration ID to the server that will handle your device registration. This will be either your server or a third party server like [AirBop](http://airbop.com/) or [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/).

You should probably take a look at the [GCM Demo Application](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html) tutorial and the GCM Architectural Overview, along with the [GCM sample](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/).

From the Google Docs:

> This is the sequence of events that occurs when an Android application running on a mobile device registers to receive messages:
>
> (1) The first time the Android application needs to use the messaging service, it fires off a registration Intent to a GCM server.
>
> This registration Intent (com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER) includes the sender ID, and the Android application ID.
>
> Note: Because there is no lifecycle method that is called when the application is run for the first time, the registration intent should be sent on onCreate(), but only if the application is not registered yet.
>
> (2) If the registration is successful, the GCM server broadcasts a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent which gives the Android application a registration ID.
>
> The Android application should store this ID for later use (for instance, to check on onCreate() if it is already registered). Note that Google may periodically refresh the registration ID, so you should design your Android application with the understanding that the com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent may be called multiple times. Your Android application needs to be able to respond accordingly.
>
> (3) To complete the registration, the Android application sends the registration ID to the application server. The application server typically stores the registration ID in a database.
>
> The registration ID lasts until the Android application explicitly unregisters itself, or until Google refreshes the registration ID for your Android application.

You are on step three in the above list. You can see how the gcm-demo-client performs step three by looking at the register() method in the [ServerUtilities](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/samples/gcm-demo-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/ServerUtilities.java) class

Answer (score 2):

Here is an image which describe all the steps to send a message from server (your webservice) to your device via GCM server.

[image]

Step 1 and 2 are already done (if I understand what you said) because you retrieve the registration ID.

SO you've to follow the next steps to get your notification.

Hope this help you!